# Which PHP Framework?

Tags: php, frameworks

I was handed a php project without and documentation or guidance and told to run with it. My first task is to figure out what framework was used or if no framework was used.

Would somebody be able to tell by the project structure what php framework might have been used. [D] are folders, [F] are files

```
[D] Root
    [D] admin (empty)
    [D] cgi-bin (empty)
    [D] conf 
        [D] pma  
        [F] config.php
    [D] css
    [D] images
    [D] includes  (where all the files are located for the project
        [D] admin
            [D] modules
                [F] 404.php
                [F] adminHome.php
                [F] admLogin.php
                [F] company.php
                [F] more files ...
            [F] appHead.php
            [F] footer.php
            [F] header.php
            [F] navigation.php
        [D] app
            [D] modules
                [F] 404.php
                [F] admin.php
                [F] ajaxGW.php
                [F] form.php
                [F] more files ...
            [F] appHead.php
            [F] footer.php
            [F] header.php
            [F] navigation.php
        [D] classes
            [F] PHPMailer.class.php
        [D] functions
            [F] admin.php
            [F] backend.php
        [F] config.php Populates a global config array with varies constants such as defaultmodule, noHeaderFooter module, imageTypes, admin script
    [D] js
    [D] media
```

Comment: Looking at the code comments in the config, indexes, etc. would probably have a better chance of revealing any framework used than this dir structure, which seems pretty "generic" to me.

Comment: There are no comments in the config files or the code it self. I tried comparing the above structures against some of the popular php mvc framework but there is no routing table anywhere.

Comment: There is posibility that this don't use any framework. And all it's written from scratch.